# How to re-verify credit card in vault before sale transaction in Braintree

Tags: braintree

How can I re-verify payment method [credit card] in vault before doing sale transaction.

**Note:** CVV and AVS rules are enable.

**Scenario is:**

- Customer in braintree vault doing sale transaction with payment method [Credit card] in vault.
- I want to re-verify credit card before sale transaction to make sure credit card is not expire.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on how you are integrated with Braintree.  Are you using their Hosted Fields?  Drop-In?

Basically, according to their docs, you would [create a nonce that contains only the CVV](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/faq/javascript/v2#can-i-verify-the-cvv-when-a-customer-uses-or-updates-a-vaulted-card?) you prompted the user for.

```
braintree.setup('YOUR_CLIENT_TOKEN', 'custom', {
  id: 'my-sample-form',
  hostedFields: {
    cvv: {
      selector: '#cvv'
    }
  }
});
```

Once you have that nonce, you can pass it to a PaymentMethod.update() call for the appropriate payment method token, and ensure verify_card is set to true.

```
result = braintree.PaymentMethod.update("the_payment_method_token", {
    "payment_method_nonce": nonce_from_the_client,
    "options": {
        "verify_card": True,
    }
})
```

Found at https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/#card-verification

Comment: So we can use update() method in order to re-verify and for this we need to generate payment method nonce using payment method token again right ?

Comment: According to the docs, yes.  It seems the CVV is needed to re-validate, so you would pass the nonce just containing the CVV in the update call.

Comment: We can also use this method https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method-nonce/create/php
to create nonce right [using payment token]?